# RestKit/RestKit.h file not found.

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit

I am following these steps found here exactly:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial

However.... I get the error:

[image]

What could be causing this? should I change the header search path? I am not really sure where to start.

Comment: Make absolutely sure that the Header Search path is exactly as it should be - it's easy to miss a relative path, which will result in missing header errors.

Comment: i basically just ended up explicitly making a reference to the direct header path and that worked cheers.

Comment: @jimbob how did u make the reference to the direct header path?
i am actually facing the problem of Restkit.h not found after i upgraded into Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had the same error with that tutorial.

But then I used this tutorial and it worked: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x

Not sure what was different though..

Jose Rodrigues

Comment: This other tutorial made the trick.
Actually, I was missing the "header search path" configuration:

For all the values, enter "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers" and voilà!

Comment: I was missing the quotes around `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers`. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated th cocoa pods and pod file as well but on xcode 6 I am still facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Followed the installation on the restkit github page, linked above, and it still doesn't work. Still says "file not found".

I noticed the libRestKit.a file is/was red so I had to search and find out from some other proejct in the DerivedData folder and copied to the place where it should be in my current project. Now the red libRestKit.a text is white. So I clean and try to build again. Still get "file not found".